# Items unclickable/selectable/focusable in IE after being hidden/shown with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I have a set of tabbed divs that I am hiding and showing with jQuery hide() and show(), this works great in all browsers except IE where the tabbed elements that have been hidden, when shown, are not clickable as links, or focusable/selectable as form select, text field, etc.

Has anybody had experience with this? Is there some sort of reset that I could do for IE to render these items reachable?

Comment: Can you throw up a demo?

Comment: the first thing I'd do is go accept some answers to questions where people have already spent their time helping you out.

Comment: @meder no but he can burp the national anthem.

Comment: Gotta agree w/ Jim.  I answered one of Gordon's questions yesterday which he didn't accept though he left a comment saying it worked.

Comment: Calvin - your solution didn't work, it pointed me in the direction of solutions that did and so I just wanted to thank you for offering advice. This site, if a spate of rude comments I have received is any indication seems to have become overwhelmed with people that seem to be more concerned with having their answers upvoted or accepted than sharing knowledge, which I find sad.

Comment: well...I for one up you cheer up Gordon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our designer ended up solving this with the CSS being updated when we show/hide tabs:

.tab_current { 
  position: relative; 
  z-index: 1; 
}
.tab_hidden { 
  position: relative; 
  z-index: -1; 
}